# Error Handling on Monix parallel tasks (using parMap)

Tags: scala, asynchronous, monix

I am trying to use monix to do parallelize certain operations and then perform error handling

Lets say I am trying to parse and validate a couple of objects like this

```
def parseAndValidateX(x: X) Task[X]
```

and

```
def parseAndValidateY(y: Y): Task[Y]
```

Here X and Y are some types I have defined.

Now each of these methods evaluates some criteria and returns a Task. If the evaluation fails, I have some code of the form

```
Task.raiseError(new CustomException("X is invalid because certain reasons a,b,c"))
```

I have a similar task raise for Y.

```
Task.raiseError(new CustomException("Y is invalid because certain reasons a',b',c'"))
```

Now I have this type

```
case class Combined(x: X, y: Y)
```

and I defined this

```
private def parseAndValidateCombined(x: X, y: Y): Task[Combined] = {
  val xTask = parseAndValidateX(x)
  val yTask = parseAndValidateY(y)
     
  Task.parMap2(xTask, yTask) {
    (xEval, yEval) => SecretData(xEval, yTask)
  }
}
```

This should allow me to run the validation in parallel, and sure enough I get the response.

However I also want this behavior

**In the event both tasks fail, I want to return an error like this**

```
Task.raiseError(new CustomException("X is invalid because certain reasons a,b,c and "Y is invalid because certain reasons a',b',c'"))
```

I cannot seem to do this. Depending on which of the two tasks fail, I can only be able to get one of the two failures on the onRecover method of the parMap2 output.

In case both do fail, I only get the error for task X.

Is it possible for me to accomplish what I am doing with Monix in a fully async way (for instance maybe some other method to compose tasks together)? Or would I have to block the exec, get the errors individually and recompose the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `parMap2` only, it is not possible to accomplish what you want to do.
The [documentation](https://monix.io/api/current/monix/eval/Task$.html) says:

> In case one of the tasks fails, then all other tasks get
> cancelled and the final result will be a failure.

However, it is possible to accomplish want you to want *exposing* errors, and not hiding behind the monadic handling. This is possible via `materialize` method.

So, for instance, you can implement your method as:

```
private def parseAndValidateCombined[X, Y](x: X, y: Y): Task[Combined] = {
  val xTask = parseAndValidate(x).materialize // turn on Task[Try[X]]
  val yTask = parseAndValidate(y).materialize // turn on Task[Try[Y]]
     
  Task.parMap2(xTask, yTask) {
    case (Success(xEval), Success(yEval)) => Success(SecretData(xEval, yEval))
    case (Failure(_), Failure(_)) => Failure[Combined](new CustomException(....))
    case (Failure(left), _) => Failure[Combined](left)
    case (_, Failure(right)) => Failure[Combined](right)
  }.dematerialize // turn to Task[Combined]
}
```